# elastic beanstalk application can't find private docker image

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, docker, dockerhub

I am attempting to setup a simple Elastic Beanstalk application with the following settings:

- Web server environment
- Predefined configuration: docker
- Environment type: single instance

My `Dockerrun.aws.json` has the `authentication` block, which was created by running the `docker login` command on my local machine. I have added those credentials in the form of a .dockercfg file to an S3 bucket and given the necessary IAM roles to the EC2 instance so that it can access the config file with the authentication information.

However, when I attempt to start up the instance, the creation process fails and the log tells me:

`Error: image mydockeruser/my-docker-app:latest not found`

It says the image can't be found, but the image IS there (in a private repo), with the "latest" tag. To prove it to myself, I can go to https://hub.docker.com/r/mydockeruser/my-docker-app/tags/ and I can see the image with tag name of "latest" including the size of the image, etc.

Any idea why Elastic Beanstalk wouldn't be able to find the image during the application setup process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the wrong format in my .dockercfg file. They changed the format from (I believe) Docker 1.6 and later.

```
{
  "https://index.docker.io/v1/" :
  {
    "auth" : "mywackyauthcode",
    "email" : "myemail@email.org"
  }
}
```